# Python: running multiple functions concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am using Pycharm for running my Python code. I have a function that combines multiple excel files in a folder and write to a csv file. I have 5 folders which I want to create 5 csv files for. Right now, I am running this sequentially, i.e., one folder after a folder. This takes quite a long time. I have another option:running the same code, but using 5 different Pycharm projects. This works. But I am wondering if there is a way to run this function 5 times concurrently in 1 single project?
My pseudo code is:

```
combine("folder1", "csvfile1")
combine("folder2", "csvfile2")
combine("folder3", "csvfile3")
combine("folder4", "csvfile4")
combine("folder5", "csvfile5")
```

Comment: Python's `multiprocessing` module can help you utilize multiple cores. Check the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html. Do note that the `threading` module does not use multiple cores, but multiprocessing is pretty easy to set up.

Comment: updated my answer to add more details fyr..

Answer (score 1):

Try using `multiprocessing` to map the function `combine` to separate cores and run it asynchronously. Here is an example -

```
#!pip install multiprocessing
import multiprocessing as mp

fo = ["folder1","folder2","folder3","folder4"]
fi = ["csvfile1","csvfile2","csvfile3","csvfile4"]

def combine(a,b):
    #YOUR CODE HERE
    print("Completed: ",a,'->',b)

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4) #Set this to the max number of cores you have
results = [pool.apply_async(combine, args=(x)) for x in zip(fo,fi)]
```

```
Completed:  folder2 -> csvfile2
Completed:  folder1 -> csvfile1
Completed:  folder3 -> csvfile3
Completed:  folder4 -> csvfile4
```

Each iteration of function is run asynchronously and in parallel for better utilization fo your resources.

[image]

---

As **Furas** pointed out, you can now use `starmap` (and its async version) since `multiprocessing` now supports it ([added in version 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap)). This helps mapping a tuple of params to a function directly instead of the iterating and applying over `zip`.

```
results = pool.starmap_async(combine, zip(fo,fi)) #async version
results = pool.starmap(combine, zip(fo,fi)) #sync version
```

If you have a `return` as part of your function and you want to retrieve those values, for the synchronous version you can simply get it from `result` but for the asynchronous version, you will need a `result.get()`

Comment: shorter `results = pool.starmap_async(combine, zip(fo,fi))`

Comment: Thanks. A quick question: My code prints the name of each file in the folder. So if we run this concurrently, the file names in 4 folders would be printed together right? This would not cause any issue? just double checking

Comment: @duckman it will mix names from different folders on screen but every process works separatelly in own folder and it works correctly.

Comment: The print statements will be in the order of completion of the task. The task itself would not be affected atall.

Answer (score 1):

Akshay Sehgal already explain you how to use it. I add only few information.

You can write it shorter using `map()` (for single argument) or `starmap()` (for many arguments)

```
 results = pool.starmap_async(combine, zip(fo,fi))
```

if you use `async` version then you may need `.get()` to wait for all results

```
def combine(a,b):
    return b

results = pool.starmap_async(combine, zip(fo,fi))
print(results.get())
```

if you will use non-async version then you don't need `.get()

```
def combine(a,b):
    return b

results = pool.starmap(combine, zip(fo,fi))
print(results)
```

Processes may `print()` at the same time and it may mix messages from different processes so it it good to create one string before printing

```
print(f"Completed: {a} -> {b}")
```

---

```
import multiprocessing as mp

fo = ["folder1","folder2","folder3","folder4"]
fi = ["csvfile1","csvfile2","csvfile3","csvfile4"]

def combine(a,b):
    #YOUR CODE HERE
    print(f"Completed: {a} -> {b}") # it is good to create one string to display all as one string without strings from other processes
    return b

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)

# async version

results = pool.starmap_async(combine, zip(fo,fi))
# it needs `.get()` because it is `async`
print(results.get())

# non-async version

results = pool.starmap(combine, zip(fo,fi))
# it doesn't needs `.get()` because it is not `async`
print(results)
```